# Reading a file, splitting it in parts and passing it to other classes without over-using memory or CPU

Tags: c++, class, csv, memory

I am beginning to move to C++ and got stuck with a conceptual question on how to make different classes work together in the correct way.

So, in general lines, what I am trying to do is basically to read the contents of a CSV file database, do some operations and math on different parts of it, and then pass these different parts to different classes, from where they will be properly accessed/inputed, etc.

In more detail, I have a class `ReadCSV`. Its constructor has a code that reads a CSV file, split it by commas (obviously), also makes some organizing on the the data that was read and, finally, separates the data in 3 parts, storing each in one public array: `array1`, `array2` and `array3`. Something like:

```
class ReadCSV
{
public:
    int *array1 = new int[1000];
    int *array2 = new int[1000];
    int *array3 = new int[1000];

private:
    ReadCSV::ReadCSV() //constructor of class ReadCSV
    {
        //code here reads the CSV
        //code here makes some math on the read data
        //code here splits the final data in three parts and saves each in an array :array1, array2 and array2.
    }

    ReadCSV::~ReadCSV() //destructor of class ReadCSV
    {
        delete[] array1;
        delete[] array2;
        delete[] array3;
    }
}
```

Now, I want each of my `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC` to store each of these different parts of the data that was read with `ReadCSV`, thus my main code can handle each part by separately calling something like `ClassA.GetValue`, `ClassB.Organize`, etc.

1) The first solution I tried was to call the following in the main loop of my main code:

```
ReadCSV mycsvread;
ClassA mya.StoreArray(mycsvread.array1);
ClassB myb.StoreArray(mycsvread.array2);
ClassC myc.StoreArray(mycsvread.array3);
```

Where `.StoreArray()` is a public member of those 3 classes that just sets the array with which each will work. That solution works, of course, but the problem is in that since such code has to be in the main loop of my application, I end up wasting memory since `mycsvread` never goes out of scope. Consequently, the content of `array1`, `array2` and `array3` becomes duplicated in memory.

2) Next, I tried to make classes `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC` inherit from `ReadCSV`, keeping its constructor and just adding over their own specialized functions. That way, the stuff inside `ReadCSV` only lasts during the scope of its use inside those 3 classes. Then it would just be the case of declaring the classes like:

```
ClassA mya;
ClassB myb;
ClassC myc;
```

That solution also works, sure thing, but then what I am wasting is CPU, because each time I declare any of the 3 classes, I am wastefully re-reading the CSV file and redoing all the work on the data, since the constructor of `ReadCSV`is recalled again.

Finally, my question in the end is: what would be the best way to do that? I mean, to have `ReadCSV` to read the CSV file and do it business on the data, then pass different resulting parts of the data to `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC`, but without `ReadCSV` staying in the memory after that?

Comment: Do your need different classes or different variables (instances of classes)?  Classes should define purposes and something that you can make one or more variables from.  Consider a class as a stencil.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for commenting. So, what I need is not different instances. I think I need indeed to have 3 classes, each handling a different part of the data that were read and organized by the `ReadCSV` class, because those 3 classes will each have mostly different private and public member functions (i.e. will perform different behaviors).

Comment: I would try a different approach.  A class would represent a record or line in the CSV file.  A `std::vector` would contain multiple instances (records).  The process would be to have an instance of the record, read a line of data.  The loop would then `push_back` the instance into a vector.  Use different classes for different types of records; if the format in the CSV file changes, you may want to have another class.

Comment: @4386427 Yeah yeah, I was just representing the thing. But I edited to prevent misunderstanding. Thanks for pointing

Comment: There are many ways to approach your question, so it is difficult to come up with a good answer. My first thoughts are: Why not use vectors instead of dynamic arrays? Why let `ReadCSV` exist after it has read the file? I guess I would pass 3 vector references to the constructor of `ReadCSV` and let it died as soon as the file was read. The vector (references) could then be passed to the other classes.

Comment: @4386427 Hmm, I am open to change for multi-dimensional vectors, no problem there. The core of the question, though, is in the last part of your comment: I don't want to keep `ReadCSV` existing. That is precisely what I trying to achieve in the proper way: how to use it just to read the stuff, but then allocate different parts of the data in different classes

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's a fairly reasonable approach, but doesn't it in the end just recreates the main problem I'm facing? I mean, to fill a `std::vector<record>`, the `ReadCSV` would read the file first but then stay in memory, because it won't lose scope (since the transfer from `ReadCSV` to `std:;vector<record>` naturally would have to happen within the main loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would do something like:

```
class ReadCSV
{
    public:
    ReadCSV(string filename, vector<int>& typeA, vector<int>& typeB, vector<int>& typeC)
    {
        // Read the file and fill the vectors, e.g.
        typeA.push_back(42);
    } 
};

class Base
{
    public:
    Base() {}
    vector<int>& getData(){ return data; }

    private:
    vector<int> data;
};

class ClassA : public Base {};
class ClassB : public Base {};
class ClassC : public Base {};

int main()
{
    ClassA myA;
    ClassB myB;
    ClassC myC;

    {
        ReadCSV("filename.csv", myA.getData(), myB.getData(), myC.getData());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so that `ReadCSV` reads data directly into the class that will process it. No extra copying will be done and `ReadCSV`can go out of scope (i.e. be destructed) as soon as the file has been read.

Comment: Simple and perfect solution, that avoids even copying the data unnecessarily. Thanks for your answer.